# Vue.js simple accordion how to open and close the same item

Tags: vue.js, accordion

I have created a simple accordion as the bootstrap-vue version was over complicated for my needs

```
<template>
    <div>
        <li class="nav-item" v-for="(item, index) in items" @click="toggleItem(index)"">
            <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#">
                <i class="fas fa-fw fa-folder"></i>
                <span>{{item.text}}</span>
            </a>

            <transition name="slide">
                <div v-if="isActive === index" class="item-active">
                    <div class="bg-white py-2 rounded">
                        <h6 class="collapse-header">Custom Components:</h6>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="buttons.html">Buttons</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="cards.html">Cards</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </transition>
        </li>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            items: [
                { text: "Page" },
                { text: "Page 2" }
            ],
            isActive: null
        }
    },
    methods: {
        toggleItem(index) {
            this.isActive = index;
        },
    }
};
</script>
```

It opens and closes the other divs when I click the link, however I can't close and already opened div.

How can I fix the code so I can open and close the same div?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your toggle method you need to set `this.isActive` to `null` if the same item is clicked again.

```
methods: {
  toggleItem(index) {
    this.isActive = this.isActive === index ? null : index;
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, there is an extra double quotes (`"`) after the `@click` on the `li`.

Refactor `toggleItem` to:

```js
toggleItem(index) {
  this.isActive = (this.isActive === index) ? null : index;
}
```

This will set `isActive` to null if `index` matches `isActive`, otherwise set `isActive` to `index`.